# Preventing my Macro from getting stuck in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The point of my macro: to reset my cashdrawer to $200 and telling my closing manager the number of each type of bill to pull from the drawer. Right now it will work most of the time and then randomly (i know it's not random but anyways...) I will hit my macro button and it then just gives me the pinwheel of death. Also, when it does "work" occasionally it will pull one less penny from the drawer than it should.

I am new to VBA coding - this is my first project. I have tried rotating around my if-statements within my while loop and gotten the same results as described above about looping and being a penny off.

I also initially tried setting the loop to While "this" ANDALSO "that" but it was like the code did not work as written so I ditched ANDALSO for a while loop with an embedded if-statement

Duplicate of Spreadsheet found here:

https://tangandbiscuitcom-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/alatham_tangandbiscuit_com/EVxTgZWgQxZElwSsiBf3oDcBWPtPggsuQq3Wr1cTRJAeBw?e=NOIFmm

'''' VBA Code

```
Public Sub safeDropCalculation()

'ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password" --I used this incase i wanted to protect the sheets

'tillAmount is the value of my Till minus the $200 to keep in the till

Dim tillAmount As Double
tillAmount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(8, "C").Value

'hundredCount is the bill count of $100 bills
Dim hundredCount As Integer
hundredCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(9, "G").Value

'hundredResult is the bill count of $100 to remove from the till
Dim hundredResult As Integer
hundredResult = 0

Dim fiftyCount As Integer
fiftyCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(8, "G").Value

Dim fiftyResult As Integer
fiftyResult = 0

Dim twentyCount As Integer
twentyCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(7, "G").Value

Dim twentyResult As Integer
twentyResult = 0

Dim tenCount As Integer
tenCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(6, "G").Value

Dim tenResult As Integer
tenResult = 0

Dim fiveCount As Integer
fiveCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(5, "G").Value

Dim fiveResult As Integer
fiveResult = 0

Dim twoCount As Integer
twoCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(4, "G").Value

Dim twoResult As Integer
twoResult = 0

Dim oneCount As Integer
oneCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(3, "G").Value

Dim oneResult As Integer
oneResult = 0

Dim quarterCount As Integer
quarterCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(6, "J").Value

Dim quarterResult As Integer
quarterResult = 0

Dim dimeCount As Integer
dimeCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(5, "J").Value

Dim dimeResult As Integer
dimeResult = 0

Dim nickelCount As Integer
nickelCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(4, "J").Value

Dim nickelResult As Integer
nickelResult = 0

Dim pennyCount As Integer
pennyCount = Worksheets("POS #2").Cells(3, "J").Value

Dim pennyResult As Integer
pennyResult = 0

Do While tillAmount >= 100#
    If hundredCount > 0 Then
        hundredCount = hundredCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 100#
        hundredResult = hundredResult + 1
        If hundredCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 100# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 50#
    If fiftyCount > 0 Then
        fiftyCount = fiftyCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 50#
        fiftyResult = fiftyResult + 1
        If fiftyCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 50# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 2#
    If twoCount > 0 Then
        twoCount = twoCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 2#
        twoResult = twoResult + 1
                If twoCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 2# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 20#
    If twentyCount > 0 Then
        twentyCount = twentyCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 20#
        twentyResult = twentyResult + 1
        If twentyCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 20# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 10#
    If tenCount > 0 Then
        tenCount = tenCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 10#
        tenResult = tenResult + 1
        If tenCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 10# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 5#
    If fiveCount > 0 Then
        fiveCount = fiveCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 5#
        fiveResult = fiveResult + 1
        If fiveCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 5# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 1#
    If oneCount > 0 Then
        oneCount = oneCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 1#
        oneResult = oneResult + 1
        If oneCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 1# Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 0.25
    If quarterCount > 0 Then
        quarterCount = quarterCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 0.25
        quarterResult = quarterResult + 1
        If quarterCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 0.25 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 0.1
    If dimeCount > 0 Then
        dimeCount = dimeCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 0.1
        dimeResult = dimeResult + 1
        If dimeCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 0.1 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 0.05
    If nickelCount > 0 Then
        nickelCount = nickelCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 0.05
        nickelResult = nickelResult + 1
        If nickelCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount < 0.05 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

Do While tillAmount >= 0.01
    If pennyCount > 0 Then
        pennyCount = pennyCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 0.01
        pennyResult = pennyResult + 1
        If pennyCount = 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        If tillAmount <= 0 Then
          Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop


Cells(13, 1) = hundredResult
Cells(13, 2) = fiftyResult
Cells(13, 3) = twentyResult
Cells(13, 4) = tenResult
Cells(13, 5) = fiveResult
Cells(13, 6) = twoResult
Cells(13, 7) = oneResult
Cells(13, 8) = quarterResult
Cells(13, 9) = dimeResult
Cells(13, 10) = nickelResult
Cells(13, 11) = pennyResult

'ActiveSheet.Protect "password", True, True 

End Sub
```

I expect for the macro to work each time i click the button regardless of what numbers i have in the quantity columns of denominations and regardless of how many times i have run the macro (it feels like it breaks after 4-7 times of working as expected) I also expect for the "Remaining Till Check" to equal $200.00 every time.

Comment: This breaks with all sorts of combinations, but I have just found that it consistently breaks and gets stuck in a loop when all denominations are qty 0 except for $50's when there are qty of 6 50's

Comment: "I am new to VBA coding" implies not new to coding in general and keeping code DRY is a general coding pattern. To get dry, just create a loop around the code you repeat (your Do ... Loop) and provide the differences (e.g. the Counts, Results and divider) in an array.and refactor the`Do ... Loop to its own procedure.(e.g. CoinCount). Hard for a newbie, but you will benefit a lot from that pattern.

Comment: Your missing penny is stolen by the [limited Double precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) Use Currency or Decimal instead. And be aware of the [Integer](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2) limits

Comment: Get familiar with [Integer Division and Modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/arithmetic-operators) to improve your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I put in the values as you describe and via debugging it became obvious why it was falling into an infinite loop. 
Consider your first block of looping code...
With 6 X $50, it leaves 'tillAmount' at $100. So the loop is entered (tillAmount is equal to $100). It then encounters an 'if' condition that tests a different variable (HundredCount). Because the condition for the 'if' is not necessarily met (as is the case in your example) no changes are made and the infinite loop is created.

A simple adjustment such as:

```
Do While tillAmount >= 100#
    If hundredCount = 0 Or tillAmount < 100# Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    If hundredCount > 0 Then
        hundredCount = hundredCount - 1
        tillAmount = tillAmount - 100#
        hundredResult = hundredResult + 1
    End If
Loop
```

for each loop. That will fix that particular issue but I can't say that is the only issue that exists. Because of the way you have written your code you will need to adjust each loop which is unfortunate. Good practice though I guess...

Comment: @Andy, and your code is written WET instead of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, I tried writing this in a better way, but again it is my first go at it and each non-repeatable way seemed be the wrong syntax or just flat not work.        do you have a recommended structure/outline that would  simplify my code? thank you!!

Comment: @dra_red thank you for the help! I have implemented this and it works well! I still have the issue of being a pennyResult being one penny less than it should be. Any ideas? Thank you all!!

Comment: @Andy, I ran it but it came out as working. If you set an example where it was not working I imagine the answer would fall out in debugging...

Comment: @dra_red Code in linked sheet is different. if you use condition from post you just need enough bad double fractions (e.g. 0.1) to run into double rounding error. Test with10000 dimes.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, seems like a logical conclusion. I imagine Andy could take it from there...